# Synchronization with ThreadPoolExecutor in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have written a program for executing my tasks parallelly with ThreadPoolExecutor and the method which I am calling to execute parallelly, giving errors, probably bcoz of the race condition. So I want to avoid the race condition for particular portion of the method. Below is my current code:

```
def my_multithreading_method(my_list):
    my_list.append("Hello")
    return True

def parallel_execution(my_list):
    try:
        response_list = []
        future_list =[]
        list_count = len(my_list)
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=list_count) as executor:
            for index in range(list_count):
                future_list.append(executor.submit(my_multithreading_method, my_list[index]))
            for future in as_completed(future_list):
                return_value = future.result()
                response_list.append(return_value[0])
        return response_list
    except Exception as error:
        raise Exception(str(error))
```

For example I have to avoid the race the condition inside my_multithreading_method for the operation my_list.append(), what I shall I do? It can be any operation like file operation. Along with this operation, there are many other operations, taking place before this operation inside the function. Please help me with some efficient method.

Comment: Can you please also provide the input list given to `parallel_execution` and also the error you are receiving? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @DanConstantinescu , I apologize for not able to give you the exact detail for the list due to security concerns. You can think of it like I have to do number of operations inside my_multithreading_method, among them there is one operation which is causing race condition bcoz that operation has to do some file r/w . All I want to know, how to synchronize the part of method when we are using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Lock` object to make a section of code thread safe. Below is an example how you can add a lock to protect the line from `my_multithreading_method`:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from threading import Lock


def my_multithreading_method(my_list, lock):
    with lock:
        my_list.append("Hello")
        return True

lock = Lock()

def parallel_execution(my_list):
    try:
        response_list = []
        future_list = []
        list_count = len(my_list)
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=list_count) as executor:
            for index in range(list_count):
                future_list.append(executor.submit(my_multithreading_method, my_list[index], lock))
            for future in as_completed(future_list):
                return_value = future.result()
                response_list.append(return_value[0])
        return response_list
    except Exception as error:
        raise Exception(str(error))
```

Comment: Thank you @DanConstantinescu for your help. Does it effect, if I create lock object inside the my_multithreading_method only?

Comment: It should be outside so all threads know about it and they will wait if they will see it acquired. As soon as one thread releases the lock, the other will acquire it and perform the operation and so on. Like this is will be only a single Lock object and all threads will know about it. If you declare it inside, a new Lock object will be created every time the small function is executed, which is not good.

Comment: Okay, thank you. One last question, is there any alternative way if we don't have to use the lock?

Comment: There are other synchronization primitives, you can check them here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=lock#lock-objects . Out of these ones, Lock is the simplest and most used one.